# Not getting json data from json-angularjs call to an external url with $http.get

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, controller

controller code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data.json').then(function(data) {
        $scope.artist = data;
    });
});
```

html code:

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="myController">

    <ul class="artistlist">

        <li class="artist cf" ng-repeat="x in artist">

            <img ng-src="images/{{x.shortname}}_tn.jpg" alt="Photo of {{x.name}}">

            <div class="info">

                <h2>{{x.name}}</h2>

                <h3>{{x.reknown}}</h3>

            </div>

        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? What is you console.log(data)? Are you serving your application or trying to access `data.json` directly from the file system?

Comment: console.log(data) is working properly and showing the data: Object {data: Array(9), status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK", headers: function}

Comment: It seems from your error that you are using MyController as the name of your controller in some parts of your application and myController in the above snippet

Comment: sorry for the above error i didn't save the HTML file now it is showing data: Object {data: Array(9), status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK", headers: function}

Answer (score 0):

The `$http` service has data property that is used to fetch the details.

**data** – {string|Object} – *The response body transformed with the transform functions*

Change your controller code like this

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){

    $http.get('data.json').then( function(response){
    $scope.artist = response.data;
    });
});
```

And initialise your html with `ng-app="myApp"`

Comment: How can you possibly know the structure of the received json? How can you know that it's nested under `data.data` ?

Comment: Still no data is coming from json file

Comment: What does ur data contain?@KaranTiwari

Comment: @JeremyThille I think if you are using .then, angular will send the response in data key of the response

Comment: Oh, I see, nice catch. @Vivz you should have said that in your answer :)

Comment: var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){
 
 $http.get('data.json').then(function(response){
  $scope.art=response.data;
 }); 
});

Comment: @KaranTiwari Glad to be of help. Please accept answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **Your Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("data.json").then(
        function (response) { $scope.artist = response.data },
        function (error) { console.log(error) }
    )
}])
```

Make sure you check the browser's console